# How to parse nested elements using DOM

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I'm working on an application where I want to parse an XML file containing a number of nested elements using DOM.  The following snippet is the type of XML file I'm dealing with.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<audobon>
    <bird id="1">
        <title>eagle</title>
        <link id="1">wikipedia.org/eagle</link>
        <description>Large bird of prey</description>

    </bird>
    <bird id="2">
        <title>Duck</title>
        <link id="1">wikipedia.org/wood_duck</link>
        <link id="2">wikipedia.org/mallard_duck</link>
        <description>Aquatic, omnivorous bird.</description>

    </bird>
    <bird id="3">
        <title>Crane</title>
        <link id="1">wikipedia.org/crane</link>     
        <description>Aquatic, carnivorous bird</description>
    </bird>

    <bird id="4">
        <title>pigeon</title>
        <link id="1">wikipedia.org/common_pigeon</link>
        <link id="2">wikipedia.org/passenger_pigeon</link>
        <link id="3">wikipedia.org/homing_pigeon</link>
        <description>Domesticated or wild bird</description>

    </bird>

</audobon>
```

So as in this example, I want to go through each one of the "bird" elements, and strip out the "link" elements, the number of which are variable.

This is the code I'm currently using.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File fXmlFile = new File("C:/Users/I844763/Documents/AudobonXML.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("bird");
        ParsedDataLength = nList.getLength();
        NodeList LinkList = null;

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                System.out.println("Bird Id: " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                System.out.println("Description: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Title : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent());

                //need method for setting value of i here to number of links in individual Bird section

                for (int i = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("    Link : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("link").item(i).getTextContent());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So, basically I need a means of determining how to determine the value of i in the second loop.  I thought about adding an additional element in the XML file containing the number of links included with each article, but I'd like a more flexible way to do it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not understanding, but wouldn't this do what you want?

```
//need method for setting value of i here to number of links in individual Bird section

NodeList linkNodes = eElement.getElementsByTagName("link");

for (int i = 0; i < linkNodes.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println("    Link : " + linkNodes.item(i).getTextContent());
}
```

Running your code with that addition results in this output:

```
Root element :audobon

Current Element :bird
Bird Id: 1
Description: Large bird of prey
Title : eagle
    Link : wikipedia.org/eagle

Current Element :bird
Bird Id: 2
Description: Aquatic, omnivorous bird.
Title : Duck
    Link : wikipedia.org/wood_duck
    Link : wikipedia.org/mallard_duck

Current Element :bird
Bird Id: 3
Description: Aquatic, carnivorous bird
Title : Crane
    Link : wikipedia.org/crane

Current Element :bird
Bird Id: 4
Description: Domesticated or wild bird
Title : pigeon
    Link : wikipedia.org/common_pigeon
    Link : wikipedia.org/passenger_pigeon
    Link : wikipedia.org/homing_pigeon
```

Comment: Interesting, I tried something like that before, but it didn't work.  Perhaps because I was defining the NodeList from outside the loop.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` (and many other DOM Node methods) use the current node for context. So `myDocument.getElementsByTagName("foo")` and `someElementInTheSameDoc.getElementsByTagName("foo")` will return different node lists.